# How do I split each line into two strings and print without the comma?

Tags: python

I'm trying to have output to be without commas, and separate each line into two strings and print them.

My code so far yields:

```
173,70
134,63
122,61
140,68
201,75
222,78
183,71
144,69
```

But i'd like it to print it out without the comma and the values on each line separated as strings.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Complete main section of code

    file_name = "data.txt"

    # Open the file for reading here

    my_file = open('data.txt') 

    lines = my_file.read() 

    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:

            lines.split()
            lines.replace(',', ' ')

    print(lines)
```

Comment: move your print statment inside the for loop like this ```print(lines.replace(',', ' '))``` which will yield what u need.

Answer (score 2):

In your sample code, `line` contains the full content of the file as a `str`.

```
my_file = open('data.txt') 
lines = my_file.read()
```

You then later re-open the file to iterate the lines:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.split()
        lines.replace(',', ' ')
```

Note, however, [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) do not modify the existing value, as [`str`s in python are immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). Also note you are operating on `lines` there, rather than the for-loop variable `line`.

Instead, you'll need to assign the result of those functions into new values, or give them as arguments (E.g., to `print`). So you'll want to open the file, iterate over the lines and print the value with the `","` replaced with a `" "`:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.replace(",", " "))
```

Or, since you are operating on the whole file anyway:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    print(f.read().replace(",", " "))
```

Or, as your file appears to be CSV content, you may wish to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library instead:

```
import csv

with open("data.txt", newline="") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        print(*row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for value in line.split(','):
            print(value)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code or provide a description? For reference see the answer by [DanielB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982604/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

while python can offer us several ways to open files this is the prefered one for working with files. becuase we are opening the file in lazy mode (this is the prefered one espicialy for large files), and after exiting the **with** scope (identation block) the file *io* will be closed automaticly by the system.

here we are openening the file in read mode. files folow the iterator polices, so we can iterrate over them like lists. each line is a true line in the file and is a string type.

After getting the line, in *line* variable,  we split (see [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string)) the line into 2 tokens, one before the comma and the other after the comma. split return new constructed list of strings. if you need to omit some unwanted characters you can use the [str.strip() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip). usualy strip and split combined together.

#### elegant and efficient file reading - method 1

```
with open("data.txt", 'r') as io:
    for line in io:  
        sl=io.split(',')                      # now sl is a list of strings. 
        print("{} {}".format(sl[0],sl[1]))    #now we use the format, for printing the results on the screen.
```

#### non elegant, but efficient file reading - method 2

```
fp = open("data.txt", 'r')
line = None
    while (line=fp.readline()) != '':  #when line become empty string, EOF have been reached. the end of file!
        sl=line.split(',')                     
        print("{} {}".format(sl[0],sl[1]))
```